# How Can I change all activity and fragment's background image on a single button click?

Tags: java, android, xml, background

I have different Images one is for english, one is for hindi. I am making a pop up dialog where you get the option to select hindi or english, on that click the background images depends on the lang which change as well

Answer (score 0):

In your themes file create tow different styles, one for each language with a different background, than use the `setTheme` function to flip between the styles.